# Sumproduct with max condition in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, formula

I have this formula but it's not working

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(Sheet1!A:A,2))=MAX(NUMBERVALUE(Sheet1!A:A,2))),--(Sheet1!AG:AG=A9),(Sheet1!AA:AA))
```

My problem is in the first section array of the sumproduct

```
NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(Sheet1!A:A,2))=MAX(NUMBERVALUE(Sheet1!A:A)))
```

The column A contain the below kind of values:

```
Till_Date
2016/10
2016/10
2016/11
2016/11
2016/12
2016/8
```

etc..

For each row, I want to set a condition on the month if it is the last month in the whole column, so the idea is to get the max of the right 2 digits and for each row compare right 2 digits with the max value of the whole columns.

However it is not working, feeling that im so close to fix it but could not locate the problem

Any assistance would be much much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Georges Sabbagh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are very close to the solution.

1. From "2016/8" what do you think, the rightmost 2 digits will be?
2. Even `NUMBERVALUE` will result in `#VALUE` error in cell `A1` = "Till_Date" - rightmost 2 = "te"
3. In your `MAX(NUMBERVALUE(Sheet1!A:A))` `NUMBERVALUE` will result in `#VALUE` error for each cell in `A1:A7` since all are text. So `MAX` is `#VALUE` error also.

Problem 1 is solvable by calculating the position of the "/" and taking the number after that.

Problems 2 and 3 are solvable only by excludig the errors. But `IFERROR` does not work within the matrix context produced by `SUMPRODUCT`. For this a real array formula is needed.

So maybe

```
{=SUM(IF(IFERROR(--RIGHT(Sheet1!A:A,LEN(Sheet1!A:A)-FIND("/",Sheet1!A:A)),0)=MAX(IFERROR(--RIGHT(Sheet1!A:A,LEN(Sheet1!A:A)-FIND("/",Sheet1!A:A)),0)),IF(Sheet1!AG:AG=A9,Sheet1!AA:AA)))}
```

will work for you.

This is an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. The curly brackets will then appear automatically.

Using the whole `Sheet1!A:A` range this will be of very bad performance. So you should shrink the range. `Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10000` for example. Same with `Sheet1!$AG$1:$AG$10000` and `Sheet1!$AA$1:$AA$10000`.